# Write the SQL statement to change all customers’ name start with ‘T’ to ‘F

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Write the SQL statement to change all customers’ name start with ‘T’ to ‘F’
I am trying to solve this question.

```
UPDATE customers
SET first_name ='T'
WHERE First_name like 'F%'
```

But I have to change the only First letter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have that logic backwards:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET first_name = 'F'
    WHERE First_name like 'T%';
```

If the question means "change the T to and F" then:

```
UPDATE customers
    SET first_name = 'F' || substr(first_name, 2)
    WHERE First_name like 'T%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUBSTR`:

```
UPDATE customers 
SET first_name = CONCAT('F', SUBSTR(first_name, 2))
WHERE First_name like 'T%'
```

Answer (score 1):

And one regexp option:

```
SQL> with customers (first_name) as
  2    (select 'Francisco' from dual union all
  3     select 'fixed'     from dual union all
  4     select 'FFrica'    from dual union all
  5     select 'Marof'     from dual union all
  6     select 'Taurus'    from dual
  7    )
  8  select regexp_replace(first_name, '^F', 'T') result
  9  from customers;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------
Trancisco
fixed
TFrica
Marof
Taurus

SQL>
```

Comment: Who/what prevents you? `update customers set first_name = regexp_replace(first_name, '^F', 'T');`